# Why does my print method not print all elements of my binary search tree?

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

So I've constructed a binary search tree that currently has all the functionality I desire apart from the method `string` which does not return all the elements of the binary tree. The entire code linked below. If I, (see code at the absolute bottom), for instance try to add five strings: a through c; 'a',...,'e', to a new object with the `add` method, the `string` method only prints: a c e and skips b and d as far as I can tell. The `size` method does however return the correct amount of elements(5 in this case).

```
class BinaryTree:

    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor for the binary tree."""
        self._root = None
        self._left = None
        self._right = None
        self._size = 0

    def add(self, root):
        """Add a given element to the binary tree."""
        if self._root:
            if root < self._root:
                if self._left is None:
                    self._left = BinaryTree()
                    self._size += 1
                else:
                    self._left.add(root)
                    self._size += 1
            elif root > self._root:
                if self._right is None:
                    self._right = BinaryTree()
                    self._size += 1
                else:
                    self._right.add(root)
                    self._size += 1
        else:
            self._root = root
            self._size += 1

    def string(self):
        '''Prints the entire tree as a string.'''
        if self._left:
            self._left.string()
        print(self._root),
        if self._right:
            self._right.string()

    def len(self):
        '''Returns the size of the tree (# of elements in the tree).'''
        return self._size

def new():
    """Creates new instance."""
    return BinaryTree()

#---------------------------------

test = new()
test.add('a')
test.add('b')
test.add('c')
test.add('d')
test.add('e')

test.string()
print(test.len())
```

Comment: When `add()` adds a new `_left` or `_right`, it doesn't put the new `root` in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `self._left` or `self._right` is `None`, you create it, but you don't add root.

Try:

```py
        if self._root:
            if root < self._root:
                if self._left is None:
                    self._left = BinaryTree()
                self._left.add(root)
                self._size += 1
            elif root > self._root:
                if self._right is None:
                    self._right = BinaryTree()
                self._right.add(root)
                self._size += 1
```

Comment: Thank you so very much!

Comment: You're welcome. Consider to accept the answer if it solved your issue.